# How to maximize the profit for a given equtaion

Tags: racket, maximize

I admit this is a homework question, a friend of friend of mine sought help, and reached me. Then I took a look, and liked the question. I think it should be solved using derivatives. Since the problem is interesting for me, I am into figuring out a solution.

It is a maximize profit question. Basically:

- there is a play which costs `180`
- each attendee costs `0.4`
- ticket price affects the interest - When the ticket price is `5` then there are `120` attendees. If the ticket price is lovered by `0.1` then there are `15` more attendees.

Below is the methods I got for calculating the profit

```
(define (profit ticket-price)
  (- (revenue ticket-price) (cost ticket-price)))

(define (revenue ticket-price)
  (* (attendees ticket-price) ticket-price))

(define (cost ticket-price)
  (+ 180 (* .04 (attendees ticket-price))))

(define (attendees ticket-price)
  (+ 120 (* (/ 15 .10) (- 5.00 ticket-price))))
```

I can calculate the profit with these methods, and I can tell that the best price is around `2.92` for a ticket(found by trying). But how can I get this price with another method? Should I really get into the derivatives?

Comment: See the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495835/how-to-maximize-the-profit-for-the-given-equation

Comment: It is a good idea to explicitly state that the question is cross posted. No need for multiple persons to use time to answer the question.

Comment: You may be right, but the two questions are in two different stack exchange site accuretely since they ask for two different questions with the same domain data.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Though not really cross-posted, the math. question and answers brings some useful context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this homework question (from [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/)) does not expect students to compute the answer using calculus. Nevertheless, it's a fine problem, if you feel like practicing your derivatives a bit!

Comment: There are many exersices in the link you've given. Do you know which exersice is this question refers?

Comment: Looks like this comes from the '2e' edition: section 2.3, exercise 30. [Here's a link to the section](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3acomposing%29)